# What does the notation (((nodeptr) (bodyptr)) -> type) mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I came across a piece of code that looks like this, where nodeptr and bodyptr are pointers to a struct, and type is a member of the struct.

```
#define Type(x) (((nodeptr) (x))->type)
```

What does it mean to have two pointers next to each other in brackets? I get that the -> notation  gets the member of the struct, but am not sure about the first part of the line. I'm fairly new to C and am trying to get my head around pointers!

Comment: is this taken from macro?

Comment: Yes I think so. It starts with #define Type(x) where x would be a bodyptr

Comment: Please write the whole define statement

Comment: #define Type(x)   (((nodeptr) (x))->type)

Comment: Are you familiar with preprocessing? Its a cast.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cast.
In this part, `((nodeptr)(bodyptr))`, The pointer `bodyptr` is casted as pointer of type `nodeptr`, then it accesses the member `type` of the structure pointed to by `bodyptr`.
I.e.

```
void *GetStructPtr(void);    //The function returns a pointer to void

typedef struct    //This is our structure
{
    float a;
    int type;
} node;
type def node *nodeptr;  //This is our pointer type

void my func(void)
{
    void *bodyptr;    //Here we have a generic void pointer
    bodyptr = GetStructPtr();    //Assign to it the vallue returned from function
    //In the next line we cast our void* to a pointer to a structure node
    //and then access its member type.
    ((nodeptr)bodyptr)->type = 0;
}
```

In your case it has been inserted in a macro to make it easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

It is cast. The pointer `bodyptr` is being casted to `nodeptr` and then `type` member accessed. This means that instead of accessing `type` member directly from `bodyptr` it is first converted to pointer of type `nodeptr` and only then accessed. It is useful e.g. when first pointer is just a pointer to *raw* memory, of type `void *` and you want to treat this memory as given type, maybe some struct.

Example:

```
struct e {
    int a;
    double b;
};

struct e foo { 1, 2.0 };
void *pFoo = &foo; // p points at foo now
// I know p is now address of object of type struct e
// and I want to get it's 'a' element BUT I can't
// do p->a, p is of void* type, yet I can do
int a = ((struct e*)(pFoo))->a;
```